# In R: if statement gives 'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' error, but there are no missing values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have written a function to identify peaks in a series of acceleration values. (I am aware of the quantmod package & findPeaks function, but it doesn't identify peaks according to my criteria.) I want to identify a peak as any value that follows three consecutive increases and precedes three consecutive decreases.

Here is my function... I apologise if it is very inelegant, but it's my first attempt at doing this. The vector x is a series of about 900-1200 acceleration values; e.g. 1.003841, 1.003570, 1.003428, 1.003261, 1.003033, 1.002630...

```
peakFinder <- function(x){
  diffs <- sign(diff(x))
  lags <- 1:length(diffs)
  frame <- data.frame(diffs, lags)
  frame$diffs <- ifelse(is.na(frame$diffs), 0, frame$diffs)
  pks <- 0

  for(l in frame$lags){
    if ((frame[l,1] == 1) & (frame[l+1,1] == 1) & (frame[l+2,1] == 1) 
      & (frame[l+3,1] == -1) & (frame[l+4,1] == -1) & (frame[l+5,1] == -1)){
      pks <- c(pks, l+2)
    }
  }
  pks <- pks[-1]
  pks
  }
```

The if statement keeps giving me the error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". This is confusing because there are no missing values in either frame$diffs or frame$lags. I am probably making some other basic error, but I can't figure out what it is.

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Yes, they are the same as row numbers.

Comment: When I run your function using the example x vector you give, I don't get the error. It returns numeric(0) for me

Comment: THe problem is `frame[l+3,1]` - this is indeed NA, and so is `frame[l+2,1]` (and im just running on a sample vector `c(1,2,3)`

Comment: Put `print` statements of all values used in the `if` conditions in your function before the `if` condition. If R says there are missing values, there are missing values.

Comment: If `l` runs on the row indices, why you want to know conditions on `frame[l+1,1]`, `frame[l+2,1]` and so on? They are all `NA`. Also note that `if (NA) {do something}` returns the error you are receiving.

Comment: To confirm, if i have `x <- c(10,11,12,13,12,11,10)` do you want to output `13` as the peak?

Comment: @rbm - Yes, 13 would be the peak I want.

Comment: @Roland - when I try the print statement, there are no missing values listed.

Comment: @nicola - I don't understand why frame[l+1,1] etc. should be NA, since there are no missing values in the data frame when I print it out.

Comment: Your index is running ot of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i think a slightly simplified version would be this:

```
  x <- c(09,10,12,13,11,09,08,10,12,20,19,18,17) # peak 13 and 20
  if (length(x) >= 7) # assuming length > 7
  {
    diffs <- sign(diff(x))
    pks <- 0
    for(i in 3:(length(diffs)-3))
    {

      if (all(diffs[(i-2):(i)]==+1) && all(diffs[(i+1):(i+3)] == -1))
      {
        print(paste("Peak at", x[i+1]))
      }
    }
  }
```

when executed prints

```
[1] "Peak at 13"
[1] "Peak at 20"
```

so you can adopt it to your function.

Comment: (I removed the `lags` and the need to use `data.frame` as i dont think you need them, but you can adopt it to your needs)

Comment: Thanks, that's much cleaner. I stop getting the error when I specify `for(i in 3:(length(diffs)-3))`. I think that's also what @Roland was referring to in his comment above, if I understand correctly!